# scraping sports data using requests or selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape data from this page:
https://www.sofascore.com/betting-tips-today

I created this code but dont work:

```
import requests

url = "https://www.sofascore.com/betting-tips-today"

r = requests.get(url).json()

print(r)
```

I tried selenium, but don't work:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
options = Options()
# options.add_argument("--headless")          #headless
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--incognito')   

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:/chromedriver.exe", options=options)

u = "https://www.sofascore.com/betting-tips-today"
driver.get(u)

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class^='Content__PageContainer-sc-']")))

time.sleep(20)
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*")
source_code = elem.get_attribute("innerHTML")

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
# print(len(soup.find_all('h2')))
# print(len(soup.select('.ivqpwB')))
parent_soup = soup.find('h2', text=("Odds") ).parent.parent.select('div:nth-of-type(2) > div')
print(len(parent_soup))
for i in parent_soup:
    print(i)
```

Any idea how I can scrape data inside this page ?

Comment: "don't work" what is the probelm? do you receive an error?

Comment: "Performance & security by Cloudflare" goodluck to scrape that site :-)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloudflare

Comment: Expected output?

Comment: data from the table "Odds": Match, Match Odds, Team, Chance of winning based on odds, Chance of winning based on history

Answer (score 0):

You could try like this:

```py
import time

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")
options.add_argument("--incognito")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    executable_path=r"C:/chromedriver.exe", options=options
)
u = "https://www.sofascore.com/betting-tips-today"
driver.get(u)

# Get the page
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located(
        (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class^='Content__PageContainer-sc-']")
    )
)
time.sleep(20)

# Get the table
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    '//*[@id="__next"]/main/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/table'
)
source_code = elem.get_attribute("innerHTML")

# Parse the html
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")

# Get the interesting data for each row
data = []
for row in soup.find_all("tr")[4:]:
    infos = []
    for item in row.find_all("td"):
        for label in item.find_all("div"):
            infos.append(label.text)
        infos.append(item.text)
    data.append(infos[3:5] + infos[13:14] + infos[16:17] + infos[20:])

print(data)
# Outputs
[['La Guaira', 'América Cali', '3.25', '3.20', '13.25X3.2022.25',
'1', '', '1', '31%', 'wins 57%'], ['Hapoel Holon', 'Burgos', '2.75',
'1.40', '1', '36%', 'wins 60%'] ...]
```

You now have a list (data) of lists (one list per row). You can make a dataframe of it with Pandas and do some more work.

Comment: return error: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="__next"]/main/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/table"}
  (Session info: chrome=90.0.4430.93)

Comment: I've just run it again with success. But there was a mistake in the driver definition (I left my own path, not yours "C:/chromedriver.exe"), please run the code in my updated answer.